# Making table cell editable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery for data table handling and the data is getting fetched from server, after this process i am making table cells editable based on role system for my application but i am unable to make it work. I have used ternary operator for that but the class is not applying to table cells. I have attached code block for this below.

```
function render_datatable() {
        let table = $('#ptbl').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            'lengthChange': false,
            'info': false,
            'autoWidth': false,
            "ordering": false,
            "paging": false,
            "searching": false,
            "ajax": {
                "url": base_url + "gettbl_html/" + type +,
                "dataType": "json",
                "type": "POST"
            },
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "columns": [{
                "data": "col1"
            },
                {
                    "data": "col2"
                },
                {
                    "data": "col3"
                },
                {
                    "data": 'col4'
                },
                {
                    "data": "col5"
                },
                {
                    "data": "col6"
                },
                {
                    "data": "action",
                    "visible": ((add_mode === 'yes' && is_view === '' && (role === '1' || role === '2')) ? true : false)
                },
            ],
            columnDefs: [((add_mode === 'yes' && is_view === '' && (role === '1' || role === '2')) ?
                '{className: "updateEditableCell",targets :[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},{className: "text-center","targets": [6]}' :
                '{className: "updateEditableCell",targets: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}')
            ],
        });
        return table;
    }
```